# Website that only works in google chrome and safari

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

This is the website that I am having an issue with:

http://tempalex135a4zr4.aws.af.cm/fourpics_new_demo.html

(I isolated it to a single page). I have tested it in all versions of IE (even IE 10) and most versions of Firefox. When I press submit in one of those browsers, nothing appears to happen. In Google Chrome and Safari, a nice drop down list appears.

I am using jQuery, and tried `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the ajax based form from submitting normally. I have also tried returning false when the form is submitted. I tried putting in a Dean Edward's script, http://dean.edwards.name/IE7/, but had no luck.

I have validated my HTML through W3C and I had a complaint about non UTF-8 encoding, which doesn't seem like a large issue.

I checked to make sure that I am using the latest version of jQuery and the latest version of jQuery UI. I think ultimately the problem resides on telling the browser to use ajax instead of submitting the form normally. However, I cannot seem to do that with any version of Firefox or IE.

Comment: If your form isn't doing a postback, I would recommend changing your button to `<input type="button"` instead of `<input type="submit"`

Comment: The W3C Validator does not make mistakes and give "invalid" error messages.  [Just because you don't understand the _"Stray end tag `input`"_ message does not mean it's erroneous.  There is no such thing as an `</input>` closing tag.  `input` tags are "self-closing", `/>`... ie, like this:  `<input type="submit" id="submit" />`](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftempalex135a4zr4.aws.af.cm%2Ffourpics_new_demo.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Comment: I didn't know that input fields were self closing! Thanks for the input! (pun intended)

Comment: Not a problem.  I figured you'd want to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a javascript error in Firefox. Check the console in Firebug.

```
 $('input#submit').click(function () {
     //$("ul").fadeOut(1000);
     event.preventDefault();
```

`event` isn't defined. try:

```
 $('input#submit').click(function (event) {
     //$("ul").fadeOut(1000);
     event.preventDefault();
```